# MQTT TLS connection Python --- Vb.net

Tags: mqtt

My pc must dialogue with Amazon AWS iot.

I followed amazon wizard (node js) to create a connection and certificate for my pc.
It generated for me 4 certificate files. (A cert, 2 keys and a root-ca)

**Pippo.cert.pem,Pippo.private.key,Pippo.public.key,Root-ca.crt**

If i use raspberry and a Python script, all works correctly . It connects, publish an so on…

In the python script, i see that in the connections options, it uses and pass 3 certificate files.

```py
cert_path = "/home/pi/iot/certs/"
host = "xxxxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
topic = "Domotica"
root_cert = cert_path + "root-CA.crt"
cert_file = cert_path + "pippo.cert.pem"
key_file = cert_path + "pippo.private.key"

client.tls_set(root_cert,certfile = cert_file,keyfile =   key_file,cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,ciphers=None)
client.connect(host, 8883, 60)
```

OK it works

I need to do the same thing on a windows pc using VB.net (but I have tried also in C++ and it is the same)
On my Visual studio 2017, in my project, I installed the nuget package M2MQTT library by Paolo Patierno.
So, following the connection options and the required parameters, I wrote down the code , JUST to try a connection……….
Here I have noticed that the connection options, accept and works only with 2, TWO certificate and it doesn’t require and use the .KEY file (while python does)
So I could use only the Ca-certificate and the client certificate, NOT the private key.

This is my code ……

```vb
Dim Endpoint As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
Dim Port As Integer = 8883

Dim clientCert As New X509Certificate("D:\Optoteam\pippo.cert.pem")
Dim cacert As New X509Certificate("D:\Optoteam\root-ca.crt")

Dim Client = New MqttClient(Endpoint, Port, True, cacert, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2, Nothing)
Client.ProtocolVersion = MqttProtocolVersion.Version_3_1_1

Dim connesso As Byte = Client.Connect("TestTestTest")

If (Client.IsConnected) Then
    Client.Subscribe(New String() {"Domotica"}, New Byte() {MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_MOST_ONCE})
    Client.Publish("Domotica", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Prova"))
End If
```

If i make my program run, it arrives at the connect line and it fails.
I have tried all the nuget packages, went deeply to the connection option of each but I haven’t understood how the hell connecting using TLS and if there are some different libraries that use and accept also a third file..a key file.

It cannot connect to the AWS iot MQTT server (While python with the same certificate does)
I got the error below…..

uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException: 'Exception connecting to the broker'
Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted

if I change the connection instruction with a FALSE instead of a TRUE

```vb
Dim Client = New MqttClient(Endpoint, Port, false, cacert, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2, Nothing)
```

I receive this error message.

```
StackTrace  "   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.SendReceive(Byte[] msgBytes, Int32 timeout) in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\MqttClient.cs:line 1094" 
 "   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.SendReceive(MqttMsgBase msg, Int32 timeout) in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\MqttClient.cs:line 1117" 
 "   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod) in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\MqttClient.cs:line 567" 
 "   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod) in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\MqttClient.cs:line 512" 
 "   at MQTT.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MQTT\MQTT\Form1.vb:line 25" 
 "   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)" 
 "   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)" 
 "   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.WndProc(Message& msg)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)" 
 "   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)" String
```

Can you help me ??
Is the problem in the missing parameter options of the private key file ? That famous third file I am talking about ?

Please help me. Thanks a lot